How to tag and label parts of an array that is nested in a tagged and labeled equation
I want to tag and label an array, and still be able to tag and label parts inside the array. In my case, I'd like to be able to add tags and labels at the ends of the rows. Am I missing something? Maybe there is a better way of accomplishing this.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
First we will introduce Equation \ref{eqn:1};
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lclcl}
% Is there a way to implement the tagging of (E1) and (E2) using syntax similar to \tag{} and \label{}?
1&+&1&=&2\quad\mbox{(E1)}\\
2&+&2&=&4\quad\mbox{(E2)}
\end{array}
\tag{1}
\label{eqn:1}
\end{equation}
% For instance, I'd like to use \ref{eqn:1-E1} instead of manually typing (E1) like this:
and from line (E1) it follows...
\end{document}



The function of \tag is to replace the equation number display.  OTOH, you can insert text pretty much anythere else easily.  \label normally is used after \refstepcounter, but may be redefined inside an amsmath environment.

Is there a way to make the inserted text referentiable? How could I go about learning more about this? Is redefining \label a standard way of doing this?

You might want to use a different counter name.
Note the use of \normallabel instead of \label to avoid the amsmath redefinition.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{foo}[equation]% reset to zero
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{(E\arabic{foo})}
\let\normallabel=\label
\newcommand{\mytag}[1]{% #1 = label name
  {\refstepcounter{foo}\normallabel{#1}}% make label local
  \mbox{\thefoo}}% or \text{\thefoo}

\begin{document}
First we will introduce Equation \ref{eqn:1};
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lclcl}
% Is there a way to implement the tagging of (E1) and (E2) using syntax similar to \tag{} and \label{}?
1&+&1&=&2\quad\mytag{row1}\\
2&+&2&=&4\quad\mytag{row2}
\end{array}
%\tag{1}^ redundant
\label{eqn:1}
\end{equation}
% For instance, I'd like to use \ref{eqn:1-E1} instead of manually typing (E1) like this:
and from line \ref{row1} it follows...
\end{document}

